# Purpose of studying fields extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm making a presentation about fields extension and i would like to know for you what is the purpose of studying fields extension ?
I have some ideas but maybe i forgot some !

Comment: Look at Galois Theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The study of finite field extensions $K$ of the field $\mathbb{Q}$, called *number fields* $K$, is the subject of algebraic number theory. One studies, among other things, the rings of integers of number fields. This can also be applied to Diophantine equations, like $x^n+y^n=z^n$ and other examples.
See for example [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56107/fermats-last-theorem-in-the-cyclotomic-integers).

In the context of Schanuel’s Conjecture, one studies also [Exponential fields](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj1iuPO2urVAhVJ7RQKHcaaCQcQFgg2MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni-konstanz.de%2F~krapp%2FSchanuels_Conjecture_and_Exponential_Fields.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFe6UZr4Z4l7voKcgHozC2s2RyqZQ). The first thing to introduce is the transcendence degree of a field extension.

Comment: Yeah ! In fact my presentation is on Schanuel's conjecture so indeed extensions are very usefull in number theory !